# Make alias to document.getElementById in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, alias

How can I alias the function "document.getElementById"
I've seen it done using $

Thanks

Comment: A smarter question would have been to inquire how to create an alias *at any depth*; e.g. `document.getElementById('example').tag('div')` though as usual I'll ask that question and end up having it marked as a dup by a dup. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly the easiest/shortest way:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
```

Comment: It's not the shortest way, and certainly not the most efficient. It's totally unnecessary to apply the same context to a function that is applied anyway without `Function.apply`. Shortest form is `function $(s) { return document.getElementById(s) }`

Comment: You are right. I thought that getElementById might take an optional second scope parameter but searching the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) this isn't the case. Amended.

Comment: This is the one that answers the question without trying to add all kinds of frills

Answer (score 18):

```
var $ = document.getElementById.bind( document );
```

Comment: I love that this has had a typo for six years and nobody said anything. Nevertheless, great solution!

Comment: I love that this has had a typo for 8.5 years and nobody _fixed_ it.

Answer (score 4):

The new features introduced in ES6 let us improve on Chris Lloyd's answer, simplifying:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
```

to:

```
const $ = id=> document.getElementById(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I use in my own library. `DOM` is the class and `$` is a function which is a shortcut implementation of the `getElementById` function:

```
function DOM()
{
  this.$ = function(elementIDs)
  {
    var el;

    // If an array of element names is passed.
    if (arguments.length > 1) 
    {
      var elements = [];
      var length = arguments.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        // Call this function recursively for each passed parameter.
        elements.push(this.$(arguments[i]));
      }
      return elements;
    }

    // If a single element name is passed.
    if (typeof(elementIDs) == "string")
    {
      el = document.getElementById(elementIDs);
    }
    return el;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var el = new DOM().$("elementID");
```

You can alias it to the top level window element.

Comment: Why are you using a constructor that doesn't have any state? It should be `var DOM = {'$': function(ids) {...}}`. Also, your answer does much more than was asked, OP asked for an alias to document.getElementById. If you want  jQuery behavior, just use jQuery instead of reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

[facebook's connect-js](http://github.com/facebook/connect-js) does the following in [src/core/prelude.js](http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/src/core/prelude.js#L202):

```
if (!window.FB) {
  FB = {
    // ...
    $: function(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then, to use it, they do:

```
FB.$('name-of-id');
```

The initial block creates the global object FB. They use this object, FB, as a namespace and define all their objects, properties, and functions within it. That way, it will work with other JavaScript code as long as that other code doesn't use the global object FB.

Comment: very nice one, for these types of alias

Answer (score 0):

```
function $( s ) {
    return document.getElementById( s ) ? document.getElementById( s ) : "";
}

$( "myId" );
```

This assumes you only want to use the dollar function (selector) to get an ID. I didn't test that, but it should work.

The last time I looked at the core of jQuery, it took a string as an argument and then used a regular expression to determine what kind of selector it was.

Comment: @hal10001: This 'smells' horrible to me. Calling document.getElementById() twice seems wasteful and this function returns either an HTMLElement or a String. How about just 'return document.getElementById(s);' ?

Comment: You can return null instead of the string if you want. In jQuery, an empty jQuery object is returned if no ID is found. If you don't do something like that then you get undefined. All this really did was give an example of the dollar selector in action.

Comment: He didn't ask for a jquery $ function, just an alias to document.getElementById.

Answer (score -1):

When you've seen the $() function, it was probably some library such as jQuery or Prototype.  The $ function is not an alias for document.getElementById, but is a wrapper that extends the functionality of the function.

To create your own wrapper, you could write a function "alias":

```
var alias = document.getElemenyById;
```

or

```
function alias(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

But really, I would use one of the libraries available such as jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: +1 but you should explain that the reason creating an "alias" is as simple as that is because javascript has first-class functions

Comment: under any conditions/use will this alias ever not work in IE6/7? I've had it bug out today in some older code and problem was resolved by replacing the alias with the document.getElementById. I actually used the second type of function "alias" above. Any ideas?

Comment: The 'var alias = document.getElementById' portion of this answer is incorrect. Creating an alias as demonstrated here does not work in Firefox or Google Chrome. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340 for more information.

Comment: To complemente Grant Wagner's comment, the reason that `alias = document.getElementById` doesn't work is that when you call `alias()`, it is not passing document as `this` into the function.