# Is creating a function like getels(id) bad coding convention?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I've gotten really lazy, and I've seen way too many bugs caused by typoes in really long function names, so I  made a function in javascript

```
function getels(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Is this OK coding convention? Does it slow down the code noticeably?
Does it really matter if I use it, or should I not. It is a fairly general question, with javascript being the example I use here.

Comment: Better to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)..:)

Comment: @IswantoSan always jquery :)

Comment: BTW, I don't know jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try jQuery. However, it is fine as you are doing it. You can also do this:

```
var $ = function(id){
   return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

And then you can call

`$("your_id")` to get the element.

It will not slow down your script noticeably, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5qM7m/1/) you can see the dummy function way is about 2% slower.

Comment: `getElementById` is easy to optimize: you can put all the elements with an `id` in a hash table. It does not necessarily 'take way longer than a regular function call'.

Comment: It does if you do not know the ids you are going to call beforehand, as it generally is the case.

Comment: Hash tables can look up variable keys at the same speed as constant keys.

Comment: No, I was referring to your claim that "`getElementById` takes way longer than a regular function call because it looks around in the DOM". Most browsers will keep a hash table themselves to look up elements by ID, and so `getElementById` is very, very fast; it does not need to traverse the DOM. There is no need to do it yourself; what you had earlier was okay.

Comment: I actually don't know jquery. This might be a cardinal sin on here, but I should probably learn it

Comment: @Nicolas Hmm. The dummy function is actually about 5-7% slower on my machine

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a fairly common practice.  Specifically for `getElementById`.  I seem to remember some google library using `_gel` in this way.

I see no problem with it.

A related question:  [Make alias to document.getElementById in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954417/make-alias-to-document-getelementbyid-in-javascript)