# Adding Aliases for HTMLElement Methods, why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript

I'm aware this isn't "best practice" but I'm curious why this code doesn't work. For reference, I'm using Chrome 63 at the moment.

Typing `getElementById` everywhere is obnoxious. Suppose I have the following code:

```
var D = document;
D.getID = D.getElementById;
D.getTags = D.getElementsByTags;
HTMLElement.prototype.getID = HTMLElement.prototype.getElementById;
HTMLElement.prototype.getTags = HTMLElement.prototype.getElementsByTags;
```

If I try to use these new names, e.g. `D.getID("foo").getID("bar")`, then I get the error `D.getID("foo").getID("bar") is not a function`. What's the deal? (To be sure, `D.getID("foo")` works just fine)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954417/make-alias-to-document-getelementbyid-in-javascript

Comment: Why do you need ...getId('bar'); ? D.getId('foo') or D.getId('bar') should be sufficient.

Comment: @epascarello that doesn't answer the question. I need a solution to the problem of aliasing the method for HTML Elements as well.

Comment: @D.Braun kind of a contrived example. It doesn't work with `getElementsByTags` either.

Comment: @KevinKeith There's no function called `getElementsByTags`. It's `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: `HTMLElement` doesn't have a `getElementById` method, it only exists for the `Document` element. So `HTMLElement.prototype.getElementById` is undefined.

Comment: @KevinKeith I am guessing you did not look at all the answers. The second on used bind() which is what you needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since IDs are supposed to be unique in a document, there's no `HTMLElement.prototype.getElementById()` method. The only object that has this method is `document`.

You can add this method to `HTMLElement` by assigning the function that's bound to `document`:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getID = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

Note that even though you can use this to call the method from a particular element, it will search the entire document, not just within that element. You could use `querySelector` to limit it:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getID = function(id) {
    return this.querySelector('#' + id);
}
```

Your code for `getTags` just uses the wrong name for the long method. It should be:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getTags = HTMLElement.prototype.getElementsByTagName
```

There's no need for the assignments to `D.getID` and `D.getTags`, since `Document` inherits from `HTMLElement`.