# What does `function $(id) {}` do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon following code:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Sadly, I don't know what it does. The only thing I found about this code was here: [Make alias to document.getElementById in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954417/make-alias-to-document-getelementbyid-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

`$` is a valid identifier in JavaScript ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier)), you can use it for functions, variables and object properties. That being said, my experience makes me immediately think of [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787342/why-does-jquery-have-dollar-signs-everywhere), other developers might have this expectation too.

Back to your code: you define a function named `$` returning a call to `document.getElementById`. There is no catch here, you can use it like any other JavaScript function:

```
const element = $('my-id');
```

Comment: The reason people use `$` is because:
1. jQuery had it as universal selector function
2. it's smaller than writing `document.getElementById(id)` (you could save some bytes and keystrokes with this)
3. Chrome dev tools console allow you to select elements with this